# Migrate MEF code for CompositePresentationEvent to PubSubEvent

Tags: prism, mef

I basically try to migrate my MEF code from Prism 4.0 to Prism 6.1.0 so first problem I ran into there was no CompositePresentationEvent anymore so I changed it to PubSubEvent. This gives me the a new exeption

To use the UIThread option for subscribing, the EventAggregator must be constructed on the UI thread.

so the way you could export and import the CompositePresentationEvent with MEF made no use of a EventAggregator instance at all you simple imported the event and MEF did the job.

So simple question is there some sort of best practice for migrate this kind of code or is it just simpler to stick with prism 4 ?

Regards

Comment: Nothing changed with CompositePresentationEvent except its name.  Just a name change, and that's it.  Your exception is because of something else.

Comment: Well there must be a change in the way it works because the code I have, where I simply export the event and import it in the oder module isn't working anymore. And once again I dont have a Eventaggregator. I just want to pass the ThreadOption.UIThread to my subscribe method

Comment: I would recommend using the event aggregator and not rely on maintaining a singleton of your event classes.  I don't use MEF because it's not an IoC container, so I can't help beyond explaining we didn't change anything but the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a little late but if someone was wondering what has been done in the end ...

in short, refactoring to use IEventAggregator but still using MEF to import/export a single instance of the EventAggregator.